# Reading a file with two columns and use them to change filenames

Tags: awk

I have a text file with two columns, one representing the current file name and another representing the name I want as the final name of the file. The text file is like this:

```
JALAZR010000001.1  -  CM040670.1
JALBAP010000001.1  -  CM040694.1
JALBBH010000001.1  -  CM040712.1
JALBAZ010000001.1  -  CM040704.1
JALBBR010000001.1  -  CM040722.1
JALBBU010000001.1  -  CM040725.1
JALAZL010000001.1  -  CM040664.1
JALBAE010000001.1  -  CM040680.1
```

The file are located as:

```
Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALAZR010000001.1.gb
```

I tried something like:

```
awk -F" - " '{print $1, $2}' filename.txt | mv Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/{$1}.gb  Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/{$2}.gb
```

But I am not a experienced programmer in bash so I really appreciate any tip to how to pass the two awk outputs to the mv program (once I did not was able to do).
The expected output would be something like:

```
Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040670.1.gb
```

Thank you by your time.

PS - any other alternative examples would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `mv` from awk itself:

```
awk -F" - " '{ system("mv "$1" "$2) }' filename.txt
```

Also you can do it without awk:

```
while read N1 SEP N2; do mv ${N1} ${N2}; done < filename.txt
```

Comment: I used the second option and worked very fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something close to your suggested syntax with [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) in place of awk, ex.

```
$ parallel --colsep ' - ' echo mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/{1}.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/{2}.gb :::: filename.txt
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALAZR010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040670.1.gb
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALBAP010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040694.1.gb
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALBBH010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040712.1.gb
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALBAZ010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040704.1.gb
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALBBR010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040722.1.gb
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALBBU010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040725.1.gb
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALAZL010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040664.1.gb
mv -n -- Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/JALBAE010000001.1.gb Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi/CM040680.1.gb
```

Remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: awesome. Thank you for share.

Comment: @steeldriver Learn to use `--dry-run` It is almost like `echo` but it will also "do the right thing" if the command is a composed command like `echo {}; wc {}`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my version, where bash reads your prepared file and builds the `mv` command (including the path prefix).  The script assumes your input file with the old/new filenames is named "infile", but it can be easily changed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

my_input_file='infile'
rename_path="Genomic_data/Mito/CDS/Fungi"

while read -r old_fname discard new_fname
do
   mv "${rename_path}/${old_fname}.gb" "${rename_path}/${new_fname}.gb"
done < "${my_input_file}"
```

The `read` operation splits the input file's lines on whitespace, which makes for three fields, each written into the corresponding variable.  It stashes the middle `-` field of your input file into a variable named `discard` (which is never used) since it's not part of the file rename action.

If you want to run a test version, just make the `mv` line start with `echo`  and it will merely print the `mv` commands.

Comment: thats very nice to. Thank you very much for you effort. I will save that as a script in my project and put your name as the script author.